# imageresizer.Plugins.Watermark on classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, com+, imageresizer

I need to use this plugin to add watermarks to images using classic ASP. I had this work partially using this code:

```
dim o, b, wm, layer,textlayer 

Set b = CreateObject("ImageResizer.Configuration.Config")

Set wm = CreateObject("ImageResizer.Plugins.Watermark.WatermarkPlugin")

Set textlayer = CreateObject("ImageResizer.Plugins.Watermark.TextLayer")

Set layer = CreateObject("ImageResizer.Plugins.Watermark.Layer")

textlayer.Text = "Yeees"

textlayer.fontSize = 50


layer.fill = True

set layer("dd") = textlayer 'THIS IS FAILING

wm.NamedWatermarks("sfdf") = layer("dd") 'THIS IS FAILING TOO

wm.Install(b)


b.BuildImage "C:\lg1_1361_44.jpg", "C:\lg1_1361_44_WATER.png", "watermark=tessst&format=png"
```

Comment: What happened when you say it partially worked?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating an instance of Layer? TextLayer and ImageLayer are the classes you want to work with

I would drop everything related to 'layer' and try this instead.

```
textLayer.fill = True

wm.NamedWatermarks("sfdf") = textLayer
```

You'll also need `"watermark=sfdf"` instead of "tessst"

Comment: thanks for the answer but wm.NamedWatermarks("sfdf") is a Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<Layer>> so I cant assign a textlayer to it.

Comment: Right, you can assign multiple layers per name, so you would need to set it to an array with 1 element, textLayer.